# Firefox can't update itself in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, firefox, updates

I have Firefox 3.6.6 running in Windows 7 64 bit. The problem is this: When Firefox checks for updates (of itself, not of addons) and tries to install them, I get an error message saying something like this (I have it in Spanish, this is a translation):

> A recommended stability and security update is available, but you don't have the required system permissions to install it. Contact your system administrator o try again with an account that has permission to install software in this computer.

What I understand from this is that because Firefox is running as a normal non-Admin user, it can't update its files. Currently the only way to update Firefox is to download the installer and install it manually, giving it Admin powers when required. Is there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could install it to a location that doesn't require admin privileges to modify, like your user folder.

Comment: I'm going to try doing this, but I'll have to wait for the next update to test it since I haven't found (yet) an older version of Firefox to try updating it.

Answer (score 0):

Try running FireFox as admin (Run as administrator from context menu). Maybe then it will update itself.

Comment: This could work, but I have to enter the admin password any time I want to start Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox 25 will be able to do silent automatic updates, even if it's installed in a directory where the current user does not have write permission.

Running Firefox as admin is a security risk, don't do this.